# XPATH: select nodes of given name which are immediately following some specific nodes

Tags: xml, xpath

best shown by a simplified example:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<root>
    <A name="wrong"></A>
    <B>not this</B>
    <A name="right">
      <subA></subA>
    </A>
    <B>yes, this</B>  <!-- I want only this one -->
    <A name="right">
      <subA></subA>
    </A>
    <C>dont want this</C>
    <B>not this either</B>  <!-- not immediately following -->
</root>
```

I want all `<B>` nodes that are **immediately** following an `<A>` node with `name` attribute equals `"right"`.

What I tried:

```
//A[@name="right"]/following-sibling::*[1]
```

which selects **any** node immediately following the "right" `<A>` (i.e. including `<C>`). I don't see how to make it only `<B>`. This didn't work:

```
//A[@name="right"]/following-sibling::*[1 and B]
```

This one:

```
//A[@name="right"]/following-sibling::B[1]
```

would select the **first** `<B>` after the "right" `<A>`, but not necessarily the **immediately following** one.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You were nearly there:

```
//A[@name='right']/following-sibling::*[position()=1 and self::B]
```

gives exactly one node on your sample.

To refer to the element *name* in a condition, you need `self`. Simply `[B]` would mean an element with *text* exactly equal to `B`.

Comment: I would normally write `//A[@name='right']/following-sibling::*[1][self::B]` - partly for brevity, partly because `self::B` is a more accurate test in the presence of namespaces.

Answer (score 3):

Just to point out that you were not so far with the first XPath shown in your question:

```
  //A[@name='right']/following-sibling::*[1][local-name()='B']
```

`position()` is not indispensable here.

Comment: You are welcome. This is not really "chaining". You are just applying the predicate to the __first__ immediate following node among all those selected. This is the common way to select an adjacent following sibling.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this `//B[preceding-sibling::A[1][@name='right']]`
This returns you node which you are interested in.

Hope this helps

Comment: Doesn't enforce the preceding element being `A`, only that it has the appropriate attribute. Your answer doesn't fulfill the brief as I read it.

Comment: This should be as per the requirement!

Comment: `//B[preceding-sibling::A[1][@name='right']]` looks for the first preceding `A` element, not that the first preceding element is `A`.